# httpd in docker cannot start

Tags: apache, docker, config, volume

I'm trying to install HTTPD in docker, I wrote a dockerfile like this:

```
FROM centos

VOLUME /var/log/httpd
VOLUME /etc/httpd
VOLUME /var/www/html

# Update Yum Repostory
RUN yum clean all && \
    yum makecache fast && \
    yum -y update && \
    yum -y install httpd
RUN yum clean all
EXPOSE 80
CMD /usr/sbin/httpd -D BACKGROUND && tail -f /var/log/httpd/access_log
```

it works if I run the image without host volumes, but failed if I use parameter:

```
--volume /data/httpd/var/www/html:/var/www/html --volume /data/httpd/var/log:/var/log --volume /data/httpd/etc:/etc/httpd
```

the error message is:

```
httpd: Could not open configuration file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
```

I checked the mount point which is empty:

```
# ll /data/httpd/etc/
total 0
```

But if I don't use "volume" by default docker copys over  files to a temp folder:

```
# ll /var/lib/docker/volumes/04f083887e503c6138a65b300a1b40602d227bb2bbb58c69b700f6ac753d1c34/_data
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   35 Nov  3 03:16 conf
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   78 Nov  3 03:16 conf.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Nov  3 03:16 conf.modules.d
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   19 Nov  3 03:16 logs -> ../../var/log/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   29 Nov  3 03:16 modules -> ../../usr/lib64/httpd/modules
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   10 Nov  3 03:16 run -> /run/httpd
```

So I'm confused, why docker refused to copy them to the named location? and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documented behavior indeed:

> Volumes are initialized when a container is created. If the container’s 
>   base image contains data at the specified mount point, that existing data
>   is copied into the new volume upon volume initialization. (Note that this
>   does not apply when mounting a host directory.)

i.e. when you mount the */etc/httpd* volume *--volume /data/httpd/etc:/etc/httpd*, no data will be copied.

You can also see https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9092 for a more detailed discussion on why it works this way (in case you are interested).

A usual workaround for this is to copy your initial data, to the volume folder (from within the container), inside your ENTRYPOINT or CMD script,
in case it is empty.

Note that your initial dataset must be kept outside the volume folder (e.g. as .tar file in /opt), for this to work, as the volume folder will be  shadowed by the host folder mounted over it.

Given below is a sample Dockerfile and Script, which demonstrate the behavior:

Sample Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:stable
RUN mkdir -p /opt/test/; touch /opt/test/initial-data-file
VOLUME /opt/test
```

Sample script (try various volume mappings)

```
#Build image
>docker build -t volumetest .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.56 kB
Step 0 : FROM debian:stable
---> f7504c16316c
Step 1 : RUN mkdir -p /opt/test/; touch /opt/test/initial-data-file
---> Using cache
---> 1ea0475e1a18    
Step 2 : VOLUME /opt/test
---> Using cache
---> d8d32d849b82
Successfully built d8d32d849b82

#Implicit Volume mapping (as defined in Dockerfile)
>docker run --rm=true volumetest ls -l /opt/test
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 18:26 initial-data-file

#Explicit Volume mapping
> docker run --rm=true --volume /opt/test volumetest ls -l /opt/test/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 18:26 initial-data-file

#Explicitly Mounted Volume
>mkdir test
>docker run --rm=true --volume "$(pwd)/test/:/opt/test" volumetest ls -l /opt/test
total 0
```

And here is a simple entrypoint script, illustrating a possible workaround:

```
#!/bin/bash
VOLUME=/opt/test
DATA=/opt/data-volume.tar.gz

if [[ -n $(find "$VOLUME" -maxdepth 0 -empty) ]]
then
    echo Preseeding VOLUME $VOLUME with data from $DATA...
    tar -C "$VOLUME" -xvf "$DATA" 
fi

"$@"
```

add the following to the Dockerfile

```
COPY data-volume.tar.gz entrypoint /opt/
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/entrypoint"]
```

First run:

```
>docker run --rm=true --volume "$(pwd)/test/:/opt/test" volumetest ls -l /opt/test
Preseeding VOLUME /opt/test with data from /opt/data-volume.tar.gz...
preseeded-data
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 users 0 Nov  4 18:43 preseeded-data
```

Subsequent runs:

```
>docker run --rm=true --volume "$(pwd)/test/:/opt/test" volumetest ls -l /opt/test
ls -l /opt/test
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 users 0 Nov  4 18:43 preseeded-data
```

Note, that the volume folder will *only* be populated with data,
if it was completely empty before.

Comment: Thank you, Zeppelin, but what do you mean "mounting a host directory"? I'm using "volume" parameter, I hope it can do what the document saying: "existing data is copied into the new volume upon volume initialization", but it doesn't happen.

Comment: Mounting a volume means that you make your host filesystem folder (i.e. _/date/httpd/etc/_), available as the volume (_/etc/httpd_) inside your container, by specifying both on the command line: --volume= /data/httpd/etc:/etc/httpd. (which is a syntax for _mounted_ volumes).

That is different from simply declaring the volume with --volume /etc/httpd (note that there is no host folder path specified).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but its not make sense if I don't give it a mount point. However, I removed local path (--volume=/etc/httpd) it still failed as it created an new temp folder and nothing has been copied over also.

Comment: The workaround doesn't work as files are missing, as host volume "overrides" internal one, files which supposed to be there but once you mount from host volume, the original files are disappeared, nothing can be copied. I think the only way is mount volume before the installation. However I accept your answer, if that's what it designed.

Comment: Yep,  this is correct,  I've updated the answer to mention it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: >I removed local path (--volume=/etc/httpd) it still failed as it created an new >temp folder and nothing has been copied over also
Hmm, it should copy the data, in this case, indeed (see my sample script).
Which version of Docker are you running ?

Comment: I'm running 1.10.3 which comes from CentOS out of box.